# How to start webcam capturing with javacv

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I am new to JavaCV, i started to learn it but there is lack of documentation. so i need help. My goal in simple. Just take a capture with camera and open it in window, so i dont want to record or anything. Just open camera in window. this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FrameGrabber.Exception {

  FrameGrabber grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
    grabber.start();

    IplImage grabbedImage = converter.convert(grabber.grab());

    CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Some Title", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma()/grabber.getGamma());
    while(grabber.grab()!=null){


        frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
    }
    frame.dispose();
    grabber.stop();

     }
```

So what is bothering me is this: frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
What i need to do to get that image from camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FrameGrabber grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
grabber.start();

// Frame to capture
Frame frame = null;

CanvasFrame cFrame = new CanvasFrame("Some Title", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma()/grabber.getGamma());
while((frame = grabber.grab())!=null){

    if (cFrame.isVisible())
    {
        cFrame.showImage(frame);
    }
}
```